# How to initialize a struct with a function in C++?

Tags: c++, struct

I want to make a program that does fraction calculations, and i've made a fraction struct with 2 properties: numerator and denominator. I want to be able to initialize those properties using a function i've overloaded twice called `init(fraction x)`. The overloads are as follows:

```
init(fraction x) //Initializes a fraction struct with numerator and denominator equal to 0
init(fraction x, int a) //initializes fraction struct to a/1
init(fraction x, int a, int b) //initializes fraction struct to a/b
```

Then I try to test it and output a fraction like so

```
int main() {

fraction a;
init(a,1);

cout << "The fraction is: ";
print(a); 
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

but I just get 0/0 every time no matter what. I think it's a pass by value/reference problem but i'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Here's all my code:

Header.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct fraction {
    int numerator = NULL, denominator = NULL;
};

void init(fraction x);                          // set fraction to 0
void init(fraction x, int n);                // set fraction to n/1
void init(fraction x, int a, int b);       // set fraction to a/b
fraction add(fraction a, fraction b);                        // adds a and b and returns the sum (a and b unchanged)
fraction sub(fraction a, fraction b);                        // subtracts a and b and returns difference
fraction mul(fraction a, fraction b);                        // multiplies a and b and returns the product
fraction div(fraction a, fraction b);             // divides a and b and returns the quotient
void print(fraction x);                                    // prints the fraction (no improper fractions)
void read(fraction x);                                    // reads fraction 3 / 5 into x
void reduce(fraction x);                               // simplifies x to lowest common terms
int gcd(int a, int b);                                       // finds greatest common divisor of a and b
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

void init(fraction x) {
    x.numerator = 0;
    x.denominator = 0;
}

void init(fraction x, int n) {
    x.numerator = n;
    x.denominator = 1;
}

void init(fraction x, int a, int b) {
    x.numerator = a;
    x.denominator = b;
}


fraction add(fraction a, fraction b) {
    return a;
}


fraction sub(fraction a, fraction b) {
    return a;
}

fraction mul(fraction a, fraction b) {
    return a;
}

fraction div(fraction a, fraction b) {
    return a;
}

void print(fraction x) {
    cout << x.numerator << '/' << x.denominator;
}

void read(fraction x) {

}

void reduce(fraction x) {

}

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return a;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

int main() {

fraction a;
a.numerator = a.denominator = 1;
init(a,1, 2);

cout << "The fraction is: ";
print(a); 
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct fraction {int numerator = NULL, denominator = NULL;};` Unrelated, but don't use the `NULL` constant as `0`, use `0` if that is what you want. It isn't guaranteed to be `0L`

Comment: `void init(fraction& x) { ...}`

Comment: void init(fraction x) {
    x.numerator = 0;
    x.denominator = 0;
} don't work, because of passing by value, do like David by refference, and is bad style in C++ (should be a method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I just get 0/0 every time no matter what. I think it's a pass by value/reference problem but i'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

That's the correct diagnosis. You are passing the `fraction` by value. The changes are made to the copy, not the original object. Change the functions to:

```
void init(fraction& x);
void init(fraction& x, int a);
void init(fraction& x, int a, int b);
```

You have the same problem with `read` and `reduce`. Change them to:

```
void read(fraction& x);
void reduce(fraction& x);
```

Comment: Thanks! I always get confused on what to make a pointer or where to put address operators...

Comment: `&` here is not the address operator, but the thing that makes a reference declarator.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing this in C++, the best way is to have a constructor for your `struct`:

```
struct fraction
{
    int a_, b_;
    fraction(int a = 0, int b = 1): a_(a), b_(b){}
}
```

Then you won't need any other *function* to initialize your structure, you'll simply do

```
fraction frac{1,2}; // 1/2
```

In fact, in C++11 you don't even need a constructor, you can just use in-class initialization and if you want to change the values you rely on the fact that the `struct` is an aggregate and you can use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
struct fraction
{
    int a_ = 0, b_ = 1;
};

fraction frac1; // default
fraction frac2{1,2}; // 1/2, aggregate initialization
```

Also think about overloading operators, like `operator+` etc for your fraction, so you can write proper C++ code (not C in C++). In fact writing a `fraction` class is a typical exercise when learning C++.

Side note: your

```
int numerator = NULL, denominator = NULL;
```

happens to compile, because `NULL` is a compile-time constant equal to zero. But it's VERY BAD practice. NULL was reserved for null pointers in C++03 and not for initializing variables with zero. C++11 deprecated it and now one uses [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr), which is not an `int` anymore, so un-wanted conversions won't happen.